# Partial specialization of type parameter in template class with type & template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization, template-templates

I want to specialize the type parameter of the following template class, which has a type parameter and a template template parameter:

```
template <
    typename T,
    template <typename E> class Foo
> class Bar;
```

I tried every permutation of adding and/or omitting `.template` and `typename` in the last line of each of the following snippets, and none compiles:

1.)

```
template <
    template <typename E> class Foo
> class Bar<int, Foo<typename E>>;
```

2.)

```
template <
    template <typename E> class Foo
> class Bar<int, Foo.template <typename E>>;
```

3.)

```
template <
    template <typename E> class Foo
> class Bar<int, Foo<E>>;
```

4.)

```
template <
    template <typename E> class Foo
class Bar<int, Foo.template <E>>;
```

Why doesn't any of them work?

Regarding the last line of each applicable snippet:

- Doesn't `typename` clarify `E` is a type used by class `Foo`, or can this syntax only be used within the `{}` body of `Bar`'s class definition?
- Doesn't `template` clarify `Foo` is a template and therefore prevent the compiler from parsing `Foo <` as `Foo` "is less than", or can this syntax only be used within the `{}` body of `Bar`'s class definition?

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Doesn't `typename` clarify `E` is a type used by class `Foo`, or can this syntax only be used within the `{}` body of `Bar`'s class definition?

`typename` is only used when you are defining a type within a template definition (`class` could also be used) or when you are accessing a dependent type (a type that depends on a template parameter).

For more information (even about when `template` is used) see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

> How can I get this to work?

The name of a of a type within template template parameter can't actually be used. It's just there as a formality. You have to add another template parameter to your main template instead:

```c++
template <
    template<typename> class Foo,
    typename E
> class Bar<int, Foo<E>> { ... };
```

Moreover, if this is a specialization of the template `Bar`, then `Bar` needs a primary template to specialize:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct Bar;

template <
    template<typename> class Foo,
    typename E
> class Bar<int, Foo<E>> { ... };
```

Comment: Would you please give a complete working example? I followed your suggestion [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af96ed244245f656), and either I'm misinterpreting it or it doesn't compile. I included another alternative commented out, which also doesn't compile.

Comment: +1, that's what I wanted to have explained in the first place.

Comment: @CodeBricks Your primary template is incorrect. `Foo<E>` is a type, so the second parameter in the primary template should be also. [See here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/833ee6f2e2cb28c8)

Comment: @0x499602D2 Your solution compiles! Am I correct in concluding that your main template’s type parameter `E` is specialized to two parameters: `template <typename E> class Foo` and `typename E`?

Comment: @CodeBricks No. The name for the template parameter `E` is an arbitrary name. In fact, since the name isn't being used anywhere in the primary template, it can be removed resulting in `template<typename, typename> class Bar;`. The only specialization that is occurring is in the second template, where again the template names have nothing to do with the primary template definition of `Bar`. The only thing that matters is how the types are being configured in the specialization.

Comment: Hm, as it stands, this question doesn't answer the OP's question. Could you edit it to contain all the relevant discussion so that it stands on its own?

Comment: The name of a of a type within template template parameter can't actually be used. -> It can be used in some situations.

Comment: @Constructor What situations exactly??

Comment: @Constructor Ooo, that's nice! I guess I should have said *outside* the template. :)

Comment: Yes, I think just like you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
template <template <typename E> class Foo>
class Bar<int, Foo>
{
    // ...
};
```

You can even omit the inner parameter name `E`, since it serves no purpose.